# A monster antiderivative $\int\ln(A\cosh(\alpha x)+B\sinh(\alpha x)+C)dx$

Tags: integration, derivatives, logarithms, taylor-expansion, approximation

After spending almost a week, I gave up on finding the exact form of this antiderivative:

$$\int \ln(A\cosh(\alpha x)+B\sinh(\alpha x)+C)dx$$

What are some nice (i.e. well written and compact) approximated form? While, using Taylor expansion is welcome, avoiding Euler formula is appreciated.

---

---

BACKGROUND: I need to formulate the integral of the natural logarithm of a quantity which looks like $f(x)=A\cosh(\alpha x)+B\sinh(\alpha x)+C$. I need to come up with something compact and sufficiently accurate that I can later use it for any values of $A$, $B$, $C$ and $\alpha$. In other words, the exact solution seems to be too complicated to be used as a compact formula. (I know that the approximated form may depends on the ranges of values).

PS Even applying Taylor expansion (generated by [wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Series%5B%5B%2F%2Fmath:ln(A*(e%5E(ax)%2Be%5E-(ax))%2F2%2BB*(e%5E(ax)-e%5E-(ax))%2F2%2BC)%2F%2F%5D,%20%7B%5B%2F%2Fmath:x%2F%2F%5D,%20%5B%2F%2Fmath:0%2F%2F%5D,%20%5B%2F%2Fmath:4%2F%2F%5D%7D%5D)) does not look fun:
$$\ln(A + C) + \frac{B}{(A + C)}(ax) + \frac{(A^2 + A C - B^2)}{2 (A + C)^2}(ax)^2  + \frac{B(-2 A^2 - A C + 2 B^2 + C^2)}{6 (A + C)^3}(ax)^3 + \frac{(-2 A^4 - 3 A^3 C + 8 A^2 B^2 + A (4 B^2 C + C^3) - 6 B^4 - 4 B^2 C^2)}{24 (A + C)^4}(ax)^4 + \frac{B(16 A^4 + 19 A^3 C - A^2 (40 B^2 + 9 C^2) - A (20 B^2 C + 11 C^3) + 24 B^4 + 20 B^2 C^2 + C^4)}{120 (A + C)^5}(ax)^5 + O(x^6)$$

Comment: It is not surprising that this integral seems daunting as the final result will involve dilogarithm.

Comment: @SangchulLee Exactly. That's why I'm looking for a approximated type of solution. Do you think a Taylor expansion based solution would be a good choice instead of struggling with it's exact form? Any effort is highly appreciated.

Comment: I know little about numerical approximation, but dilogarithm is a well-understood function which is implemented in many math software. So my personal opinion is that working with its exact form is a better choice if you are thinking of working with arbitrary range of $x$. On the other hand, if you are only interested in a small range of $x$, It may possible that Taylor expansion is a more economical choice.

Comment: @SangchulLee. Just out of curiosity : how would you express the monster in terms of dilogarithms for any $A,B,C$ ?

Comment: @SangchulLee Can you please show your idea or work on finding the exact form using dilogarithms? It looks so Greek to me.

Comment: Are $A,B,C$ all positive ? If they are, the integrand is probably quite close to a straight line for $x>0$.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici $A<0$, $C>0$ and $B$ can be positive and negative.

Comment: Just setting A=0, Wolfram Alpha returns a rather large expression: http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+%5Cln%28b%5Csinh%28%5Calpha+x%29%2Bc%29dx&x=0&y=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume that you are only interested in real values. That is,

> **Assumption.** $A$, $B$, $C$, $\alpha $ are all in $\mathbb{R}$.

In particular,

$$f(x) = A\cosh x + B\sinh x + C$$

is a real-valued function on $\mathbb{R}$. Then this setting allows us to avoid some pesky issue regarding the branch cut of the complex logarithm. So let us compute the integral.

- Let $p, q$ be zeros of the quadratic polynomial $\frac{A+B}{2}t^2 + Ct + \frac{A-B}{2}$. In other words, they satisfy the identity  $ \frac{A+B}{2}t^2 + Ct + \frac{A-B}{2} = \frac{A+B}{2}(t - p)(t - q)$. Then plugging $t = e^{\alpha x}$, we find that

  $$f(x) = \frac{A+B}{2} e^{\alpha x} (1-pe^{-\alpha x}) (1-qe^{-\alpha x}) $$

  In particular, we have

  \begin{align*}
  \log |f(x)|
  = \log\left|\frac{A+B}{2}\right| + \alpha x + \log |1-pe^{-\alpha x}| + \log |1-qe^{-\alpha x}|. \tag{1}
  \end{align*}

  (Here, I am assuming that you are only interested in the region where $f(x) > 0$. Then taking absolute values causes no harm.)
- In order to integrate the above equation, we need a special function called the [*dilogarithm*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Dilogarithm). It is the function which is denoted by $\operatorname{Li}_2$ and is defined by

  $$ \operatorname{Li}_2(z) = -\int_{0}^{z} \frac{\log(1-t)}{t} \, dt = -\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log(1-zu)}{u} \, du, \quad z \in \mathbb{C}\setminus[1,\infty). $$

  (Here, the first integral is taken along the line segment joining $0$ and $z$. The equivalence of two integrals can be shown by the substitution $t = zu$.) So $\operatorname{Li}_2(z)$ is not differentiable along the branch cut $[1,\infty)$. On the other hand, its real part behaves much better since

  $$ \operatorname{Re}\operatorname{Li}_2(z)
  = -\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log|1-zu|}{u} \, du \tag{2}$$

  A bit of complex analysis tells that both sides of $\text{(2)}$, understood as function of real variables $x$ and $y$ (with $z = x+iy$), extends to a smooth on all of $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{(1,0)\}$. As a useful consequences, for any $0 < a < b$ we have

  \begin{align*}
  -\int_{a}^{b} \frac{\log|1-zu|}{u} \, du
  &= -\int_{0}^{b} \frac{\log|1-zu|}{u} \, du - \left( -\int_{0}^{a} \frac{\log|1-zu|}{u} \, du \right) \\
  &= -\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log|1-bzv|}{v} \, dv - \left( -\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log|1-azw|}{w} \, dw \right) \\
  &= \operatorname{Re}\operatorname{Li}_2(bz) - \operatorname{Re}\operatorname{Li}_2(az).
  \end{align*}

  (Here, we utilized the substitution $u = bv$ and $u = aw$ for respective terms.) This is useful when computing some indefinite integrals to come.
- Using the previous computation, we can integrate $\text{(1)}$. Indeed, let us substitute $u=e^{-\alpha x}$. Then

  $$\int \log|1 - p e^{-\alpha x}| \, dx
  = -\frac{1}{\alpha}\int \frac{\log|1 - pu|}{u} \, du
  = \frac{1}{\alpha}\operatorname{Re}\operatorname{Li}_2(pu) + \text{constant} $$

  This remains true if we replace $p$ by $q$. Therefore we get

> \begin{align*}
> &\int \log|f(x)| \, dx \\
> &\hspace{1em}= x\log\left|\frac{A+B}{2}\right| + \frac{\alpha x^2}{2} + \frac{1}{\alpha}\operatorname{Re}\operatorname{Li}_2(pe^{-\alpha x}) + \frac{1}{\alpha}\operatorname{Re}\operatorname{Li}_2(qe^{-\alpha x}) + \text{constant}.
> \end{align*}

---

**Example.** Let $A = -1$, $B = 2$, $C = 1$ and $\alpha = 3$. Then both computation shows that

$$ \int_{-2}^{3} \log |f(x)| \, dx \approx 17.88480462181253086\cdots. $$

The following is an actual computation using *Mathematica 11*:

[image: numerical computation]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Looks compact enough. However, $Li_2(pe^{-\alpha x})$ and $Li_2(qe^{-\alpha x})$ are giving me heart attack as my ultimate intention is to use this as an analytical expression (i.e. a compact formula). Indeed, those dilogarithms require another complicated integrals themselves. Is there any approximation remedy for those dilogarthims?

Comment: The big difference between what the exact form looks like with that of Taylor expansion is stunning. I will do some numerical testing to make sure it is correct and will get back to you. ($A<0$, $C>0$, $B$ could be negative or positive). If it does, I still have to approx the dilogarithms :( Thanks again.

Comment: Dilogarithm has very nice properties that enable us to compute its value efficiently, For $|z| < 1$, the following series converges absolutely: $$\operatorname{Li}_2(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n^2}$$So, as for computation, it is no more complicated than computing the value of $-\log(1-z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n}$. For $z$ with large modulus, we have various transforms to utilize. For instance, if $z\notin[0,\infty)$ then $$\operatorname{Li}_2(z)+\operatorname{Li}_2(1/z)=-\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\frac{1}{2}\log^2(-z).$$

Comment: I'm still fuzzy how this happened: $\int \log(1-pe^{-\alpha x})=\frac{1}{\alpha}\operatorname{Li}_2(pe^{-\alpha x})$. Can you please elaborate a little bit.

Comment: @JohnButler, Perhaps differentiating $\frac{1}{\alpha}\operatorname{Li}_2(pe^{-\alpha x})$ and using the formula $\frac{d}{dx}\operatorname{Li}_2(x) = -\frac{\log(1-x)}{x}$ would be the easiest way. For an earnest derivation, you may substitute $u = pe^{-\alpha x}$ to compute the integral.

Comment: I am still struggling with getting this: $\int \log(1-pe^{-\alpha x})= \frac{1}{\alpha}\operatorname{Li}_2(qe^{-\alpha x})$ :( Can you please take a look at [this link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+log(1-p*e%5E(-ax))) and Let me know how did you get it. Thanks.

Comment: I really appreciate if you can take a look at my comments and revise your answer -- if needed.

Comment: @JohnButler, Have you tried verifying $\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{\alpha}\operatorname{Li}_2(pe^{-\alpha x}) = \log(1-pe^{-\alpha x})$ or the $u$-substitution I suggested? Please let me know what makes you struggle checking this identity.

Comment: my numerical computation shows that $\int_{-b}^{+b} \log\left(A\cosh(\alpha x) + B\sinh(\alpha x) + C\right) \, dx \neq (Lx + \frac{\alpha x^2}{2} + \frac{1}{\alpha}\operatorname{Li}_2(pe^{-\alpha x}) + \frac{1}{\alpha}\operatorname{Li}_2(qe^{-\alpha x})\Big|_{-b}^{+b}$ I think I finally diagnosed the issue. For my values, $(1-qe^{-\alpha x})<0$.

Comment: So when I used [wolfram](https://goo.gl/tUWtHD), there is an extra term which does not appear in your solution (since logs inputs assumed to be positive): $\log\left(A\cosh(\alpha x) + B\sinh(\alpha x) + C\right) = L + \alpha x + \log(1-pe^{-\alpha x}) + \log(1-qe^{-\alpha x}) + (\pi-\arg(1-pe^{-\alpha x})-\arg(1-pe^{-\alpha x}))i$.

Comment: For my value ranges, the positiveness of $(1-qe^{-\alpha x})$ and $(1-pe^{-\alpha x})$  are not guaranteed and I'm hoping to come up with something compact at the end but the imaginary part does not look fun. I'm not even sure whether the problem arises from fact that I should have that imaginary part included or not. Do you have any comment? The quantity that I'm measuring is real, having imaginary in the solution does not seem right to me. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @JohnButler, My previous answer was more focused on complex-analysis aspect of the problem, but it seems to me that you are mostly interested in real values. So I rewrote my answer. Now the final result is free from the pesky branch cut issue, so you can utilize it without hassle.

Comment: Wow man, I've not read it yet but the amount of your knowledge in math is astonishing. I owe you a beer when I stop by LA. Let me digest what you have written. Thanks

Comment: It is giving me brain cancer. Here are the values that I can NOT get $\int_{-\beta}^{\beta} \log(A\cosh(\alpha x)+B\sinh(\alpha x)+C)$ equal to $x\log\left|\frac{A+B}{2}\right| + \frac{\alpha x^2}{2} + \frac{1}{\alpha}\operatorname{Re}\operatorname{Li}_2(pe^{-\alpha x}) + \frac{1}{\alpha}\operatorname{Re}\operatorname{Li}_2(qe^{-\alpha x}) + \text{constant} \Big|_{-\beta}^{\beta}$. 

$A=-2.8e-3$, $B=-4.271e-4$, $C=380.7$, $\alpha =1.6903e+5$ and $\beta=50e-6$

Comment: @JohnButler, My software gives the value $0.000593997$ for both expressions. Does it match any values you have got?

Comment: Great, man. Thanks a million for your effort. You already spent a great amount of your valuable time on this, but may I have your last advice on how to make the last expression: $$\int_{-\beta}^{\beta}\log|f(x)|dx = 2\beta\log\left|\frac{A+B}{2}\right| + \frac{1}{\alpha}\operatorname{Re}(\operatorname{Li}_2(pe^{-\alpha \beta}) - \operatorname{Li}_2(pe^{\alpha \beta}))+ 
\frac{1}{\alpha}\operatorname{Re}(\operatorname{Li}_2(qe^{-\alpha \beta})-\operatorname{Li}_2(qe^{\alpha \beta}))
$$ even more compact? (especially considering the fact that the limits of the definite integral are symmetric)

Comment: The problem is that I cannot use 

$$\operatorname{Li}_2(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n^2}$$

as in my problem, $|z|$ is NOT necessarily less than 1. I thought maybe the relationship between $p$, $q$, $A$, $B$ and $C$ and having exponential inputs to $Li_2$ might do some magic. A nice approximation also works. No sure. Any last piece of advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: fyi: I also asked this as a new question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2386332/a-dilogarithm-identity-simplification-compaction

Comment: @JohnButler, For numerical evaluation, I am by no means an expert on this. But a quick googling gives you a couple of resources for building your own algorithm, for instance, see [*this*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-ph/0410259.pdf) or [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/226148494). But most of all, any reasonable mathematical software packages (MatLab, Mathematical, to name a few) implement this function. Are you not allowed to use them and forced to start from scratch?