# A dilogarithm identity (simplification/compaction)

Tags: logarithms, approximation, hyperbolic-geometry, hyperbolic-functions, polylogarithm

I'm wondering if there is any compact expression to compute (or approximate):

$$\operatorname{Li}_2(pe^{-\alpha})-\operatorname{Li}_2(pe^{\alpha})$$

or

$$\operatorname{Re}\{\operatorname{Li}_2(pe^{-\alpha})-\operatorname{Li}_2(pe^{\alpha})\}$$

The problem is that I cannot use

$$\operatorname{Li}_2(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n^2}$$

as for my values, $|z|$ is NOT necessarily less than 1. I am hoping, maybe, having exponential inputs to $\operatorname{Li}_2$ might do some magic. Unfortunately, $p$ and $\alpha$ are pure real. A nice approximation or any piece of advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I restated the question and added my own work which did not actually lead to any further simplification. I also added some more clarification about value ranges. Should I remove the other question? Or if my explanation is convincing please remove the duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

For $|z|>1$ you can use the relationship :
$$\text{Li}_2(z)= -\frac{1}{2}\ln^2(-z)-\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{z} \right)$$
There is no particular difficulty to compute the real value of $-\frac{1}{2}\ln^2(-z)$ .

Comment: Great point! Can you think of something applicable regardless of $|z|$ being greater or smaller than 1. I'm trying to have a compact formula that can handle all inputs. In fact, my system, receive some inputs in which it's not known what $|z|$ would be. Thanks.

Comment: You can probably find in the mathematical packages a ready-made soft for the dilogarithmic function valid for any $z$ small or large, real or complex. This should be the way requiring less work. If you have to built your home-made soft, it is easy to split the code into the two cases $|z|<0$ and $|z|>0$ and use the respective convergent series. The integral form of definition of dilogarithm could be used as well with numerical integration, but it also needs to split into the two cases.